# How to get client-specific color schemes in Symfony2, based on the url that got you to the site

Tags: css, dynamic, stylesheet, symfony, twig

We have a single webinterface in Symfony2 which is used by a number of
clients.
Each client enters our site by a different URL.
For example:

- client A enters from clientA.our-domain.com
- client B enters from clientB.our-domain.com
- client C might even join from clientC.com, i.e. using their own selected domain instead of a sub-domain of ours

However, regardless of the URL they use, they end up at the same
machine: our website.

Right now we use the same CSS for all of them, regardless of which
client. We would love it if we could design **a stylesheet for
each client with client-specific color schemes**.
I don't want to set up a separate webserver for each client, so I'm
looking to select the stylesheet dynamically.

Now, in the HTTP 'Host' header one can see which URL the client used,
right.
Can this be used, for example in app.php, to set some global variable
which defines the client?
Twig might read this variable in the main template and decide which
stylesheet to use based on it, perhaps?

Also, should we then use css variables? This might be preferable to keeping complete stylesheet 'clones' for each client, if only the colors change.

So to sum up:

- Can the 'host' HTTP header be used in Symfony2 to indicate to Twig which stylesheet to use?
- Should we use CSS variables to identify the colors in the scheme, or is there a better way?

Thanks in advance!

Dieter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I'd prefer using a special CSS file for each site (containing the styling, that's different for each site, like colors or background images). E.g. `site-clientA.our-domain.com.css`.

Then you could use something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
      href="/path/to/css/site-{{ app.request.host }}.css" />
```

Or

```
{% if app.request.host in ['site-clientA.our-domain.com', 'site-clientB.our-domain.com', 'site-clientC.our-domain.com'] %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
        href="/path/to/css/site-style1.css" />
{% elseif ... %}
  ...
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thx for your reply. Using the url is idd the way to go.
Putting everything variable in one stylesheet is not sufficient for our design unfortunately. It would result in one huge, unmanageable css file in our case.
The use of CSS variables might be a solution? Then we can reference to a .css file with your url method and put all that varies colorwise in that file and use those as variables in the other css files (http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-add-variables-to-your-css-files/)
The bigger question is, what is the best method to use .css variables in Symfony?